# phonegap statusbar notification how to send offline notification daily repeating 10 times a day after app is closed?

Tags: cordova, notifications, background-service

I have already used phonegap status bar notification plugin.

It works properly but I wanted to get notification after app is closed.It gives notification Only for 3-5 hours after app is closed but I wanted to show them repeating 10 times per day for 10  days offline.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin by @Katzer which has all the features you need.

[Cordova Local Notification Plugin - by Katzer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

So, this plugin is able to send scheduled messages to the user. Therefore you need to set up sth. like a reminder (customizable date / time by user) with this javascript code:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title: "Production Jour fixe",
    text: "Duration 1h",
    firstAt: monday_9_am,
    every: "week",
    sound: "file://sounds/reminder.mp3",
    icon: "http://icons.com/?cal_id=1",
    data: { meetingId:"123#fg8" }
});

cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("click", function (notification) {
    joinMeeting(notification.data.meetingId);
});
```

This example code is a scheduled notification which the application will send every week to the user.

More information can be found inside the great documentation.

Comment: Thanks For reply Sithys.Local notification plugin shows error in catlog cannot read property 'notification' of undefined in file index.html at this code line "cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({".  I am Not able to install this plugin properly..plz help me.